# How to set a MediaSession.QueueItem's Media Path

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I'm building a ListArray of MediaSession.QueueItems with the intention of pushing the list to the MediaSession as a playlist.

I noticed that in the MediaDescription.Builder there's a way of specifying the MediaUri for the item, but it's not available before API 23.

Questions are:

1. How do I associate a media file's path to a MediaSession.QueueItem?
2. What was done after API v21 and before API v23?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this example: https://github.com/emuneee/MarshmallowFM

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    mMediaController.getTransportControls().playFromUri(uri, null);
} else {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AudioPlayerService.PARAM_TRACK_URI, uri);
    mMediaController.getTransportControls().playFromSearch("", bundle);
}
```

Just search for an exact match for the URI and it effectively behaves the same.